# display count of bookings per day using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

There's a MYSQL table `bookings` that has the `booking_id`, `booking_code`, `timestamp`.

I want to display the number of bookings in a day.

This query ,

```
SELECT `timestamp`, count(`booking_id`) 
FROM `bookings` 
group by `booking_id` 
order by `timestamp` desc
```

gives a result like as below

```
timestamp           count(`booking_id`)
2016-02-25 20:49:42 1
2016-02-25 20:42:13 1
2016-02-25 14:00:24 1
2016-02-25 12:51:21 1
2016-02-24 19:44:29 1
2016-02-24 19:08:38 1
```

I Understand why the result is like this, bcoz it's taking the day and time [timestamp] into consideration.

But What I need is a result like this

```
timestamp           count(`booking_id`)
2016-02-25  4
2016-02-24  2
```

Answer (score 0):

cool, I got it !

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS day,
        COUNT(*) AS bookingcount
 FROM   bookings
 GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
 ORDER BY day desc
```